# SQL Server Constraint (Limit bit field based on a foreign key)

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I need help with constraints in SQL Server.  The situation is for each OrderID=1 (foreign key not primary key so there are multiple rows with the same ID) on the table, the bit field can only be 1 for one of those rows, and for each row with OrderID=2, the bit field can only be 1 for one row, etc etc.  It should be 0 for all other rows with the same OrderID.  Any new records coming in with 1 in the bit field should reject if there is already a row with that OrderID which has the bit field set to 1.  Any ideas?

Comment: If non of the answers suit you especially if on a pre-2008 version you can write an insert/update trigger that will reject duplicates

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON UnnamedTable (OrderID) WHERE UnnamedBitField=1
```

It's called a [Filtered Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188783.aspx). If you're on a pre-2008 version of SQL Server, you can implement a poor-mans equivalent of a filtered index using an indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW UnnamedView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT OrderID From UnnamedSchema.UnnamedTable WHERE UnnamedBitField=1
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ON UnnamedView (OrderID)
```

You can't really do it as a constraint, since SQL Server only supports column constraints and row constraints. There's no (non-fudging) way to write a constraint that deals with all values in the table.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2000 (sad I know) so I used the Indexed view and this worked for me.  The only difference was I had to use "CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX" instead of "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX".  Thanks!

Comment: @user2263882 - I've updated the sample (I admit, I haven't had to use such efforts for years and worked from memory).

Answer (score 1):

You could more fully normalize the schema which will help you not have to hunt for the already set bit but use a join. You need to remove the bit field and crate a new table say X containing OrderID and the primary key of your table, with the primary key of X being all those fields.

This means that when you insert you need to insert into your original table and into X f and only if you would have set the bit to 1 on your table. The insert will fail if there is already a row in X which is as if there was already an original row with bit set to 1.

The downside is that this takes up more space than your schema but is easier to maintain as you can't get to the equivalent of having two rows with the bit set to 1.

Comment: I will keep this in mind if I have to change the table structure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to subclass the parent table.  You didn't mention it but a common reason for this pattern is to represent one unique active row from the set of all rows with the same common key value.  Let's Assume your bit field represents the ***active*** Orders.... 
Then I would create a separate table called ***ActiveOrders***, which will only contain the one row with the bit field set to 1

```
Create Table ActiveOrders(int Orderid Primary Key Null)
```

and the other table with ***all*** the rows in it, with it's own unique Primary Key OrderId

```
Create Table AllOrders
(OrderId Integer Primary Key Not Null, ActiveOrderId Integer Not Null,
 [All other data fields]
 Constraint FK_AllOrders2ActiveOrder
    Foreign Key(ActiveOrderId) references ActiveOrders(OrderId))
```

You now no longer even need the bit field, as the presence of the row in the ActiveOrders table identifies it as the Active Order... To get only the active Orders (the ones that in your scheme would have bit field set to 1), just join the two tables.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good suggestion.  I'm hesitant to change the table structure at the moment but I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I aggree with the other answers and if you can change the schema then do that but if not then I think something like this will do.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnMyCheck
    (@id INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT

    SELECT @i = COUNT(*)
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE FkCol = @id 
    AND BitCol = 1

    RETURN @i
END

ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT ckMyCheck CHECK (fnMyCheck(FkCol)<=1)
```

but there are problems that can come from doing using a udf in a check constraint, such as [this](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/check-constraints-that-call-functions/)

Edit to add comment regarding problems with this 'solution':

*There are more straightforward issues than what you've linked to.*

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(FkCol,BitCol) VALUES (1,1),(1,0)
```

*followed by*

```
UPDATE YourTable SET BitCol=1
```

*succeeds and leaves two rows with FkCol=1 and BitCol=1*

Comment: There are more straightforward issues than what you've linked to. `INSERT INTO YourTable(FkCol,BitCol) VALUES (1,1),(1,0)` followed by `UPDATE YourTable SET BitCol=1` succeeds and leaves two rows with `FkCol`=1 and `BitCol`=1